# How does a computer transform binary data to decimal data

Tags: architecture, binary, decimal, computer-science

I've just registered in the forum! I don't know very much about computers architecture and I came out with a doubt. If computers work with binary code (0 and 1) how do they *print* decimal numbers on the screen? For instance, if I add 5 to 6 (101 + 110 in binary), I get 11 that is 1011 in binary but how does a computer know how to convert it to decimal? Is there like a memory that stores "1011 in binary = 11 in decimal"? Then it has no sense because there's a infinite amount of numbers and a memory can't store them all...

Can anyone explain this to a *experienceless* man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the computer stores numbers as [binary representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) - 1s and 0s.

There are many different types of binary representations of numbers depending on how big the number is that needs to be stored and whether it has a decimal part or is an integer.

The computer also has look-up tables of human-readable characters (such as [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) or [UTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)) and software routines for converting each valid textual character to a font "glyph" or collection of pixels representing a textual character.

When it has a number stored in a byte such as `00011011` (which is the unsigned binary representation of the decimal number "27") code is executed on the computer to convert this to a String (textual) representation In the case of the ASCII character set, it will convert the single byte "00011011" to the *two* bytes: 0x32 0x37. Which correspond to the letters "2" and "7" in the ASCII character set.

Almost all programming languages have library routines that can convert binary numbers to their String representation like this.

Then another software routine will look up the appropriate [glyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) for the characters that need to be displayed in a particular [font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font), read the "shape" of the character and convert that shape to a collection of pixels in a process known as [rasterization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation). Finally the rasterized block of pixels that represents the two characters is copied into a graphics memory location which triggers the appropriate part of your display to display the numbers!

To actually perform any mathematics, the computer doesn't need to ever convert the binary numbers to decimal - it can perform all its maths in binary. Decimal is just a different way of looking at binary numbers so the computer only really needs to do this when it displays the numbers on the screen for humans to read.

The computer "knows" which bytes represent which characters because ALL the displayable letters of the alphabet are stored in lookup tables mentioned earlier.

Although there are a number of ways the computer can represent a binary number internally, the principle of binary representations is based on the fundamental concept of counting: Since binary is a base-2 system, each digit can represent an increasing power of 2, with the rightmost digit representing 2^0, the next representing 2^1, then 2^2, and so on. So 00011011 represents (moving from right to left through the bits):

```
(1*2^0) + (1*2^1) + (0*2^2) + (1*2^3) + (1*2^4) + (0*2^5) + (0*2^6) + (0*2^7)
```

which is the equivalent of

```
1 + 2 + 0 + 8 + 16 + 0 + 0 + 0 == 27
```

In this way a single byte can represent every possible decimal integer from 0 to 255 with a unique pattern of bits for each different decimal number. Given more than one byte for each number, the computer  can effectively represent every possible integer with a unique pattern of bits (provided enough bytes are available for big enough numbers).

Negative numbers and numbers with a decimal component are more complicated, and have different binary representations. Floating point numbers are often only approximated due to there being an infinite number of decimal values between any two integers.

*Please note that this is an over-simplification but it is the general process.*